# Swift project unit testing fail

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, target

Is it normal to add all files to tests target? I think that if you make @testable import TragetName it must automatically use all files from imported target or I'm not right?

Comment: @testable import allows the tests to import the module so you dont need to add the files target to tests

Comment: should I build project for test or something like that? because for me @testable not working

Comment: you shouldn't need to create a new project no, try following this guide and see if it helps https://x-team.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-ios-unit-tests-in-swift/